# A way to develop Microsoft Office templates similar to the Microsoft Excel “Drop-down list” template (tutorial)

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

Microsoft provides a brilliant tutorial—“Drop-down list”—as a (interactive) template for the user to learn something new.

[image: Screenshot of a window the user sees when creating a spreadsheet from the “Drop-down list” template (provided by Microsoft Corporation)]

The user can find a step-by-step algorithm for creating a drop-down list in Microsoft Excel in the **Help** pane (it shows automatically on a file creation/opening).

[image: Screenshot of a Microsoft Excel window with the document created from the “Drop-down list” template (the Help pane is framed)]

At each step, Microsoft Excel displays hints about what ribbon tab to navigate to and what command to execute, checking the correctness of the actions performed by the user.

[image: Screenshot of a Microsoft Excel window with the document created from the “Drop-down list” template (the Help pane with the algorithm is framed)]

Is there a chance that the source code of this template is publicly available? I would love to create something like this for my students. It would be wonderful if they didn't need to install any add-ons but to open a template and perform the algorithm's steps under the guidelines of Microsoft Excel (or any other Microsoft Office app).

I tried to change the template extension to `.zip`, unzip it, and examine the source code. Unfortunately, the core part of the template (with the main logic) was somewhere on the Microsoft servers, and I couldn't examine it.

Does Microsoft have any other similar templates? Has anybody tried to re-create it or build something custom identical to that template?

Rick Kirkham, is there a chance you could help?

Answer (score 0):

The source code is unavailable, but you could create an Office add-in that does similar things. One thing that you could not reproduce in an add-in is the green callouts that appear in various places on the worksheet and the ribbon as the user works through the tutorial.

There is a way to get an add-in to automatically open when a workbook opens. See [Automatically open a task pane with a document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document).

Comment: Thank you for your response, Rick. Yeah, I know I could do it with an add-in. The main issue with this approach is that the end-user has to install this add-in. I can’t force them to do it. It's much more natural for them to open a document or a template and get all the benefits of a learning process I designed and implemented in the document (template). Moreover, as you already mentioned, add-ins have limitations I would love to overcome. I was hoping that you might know the author of this template. If not, well, maybe one day, we’ll find the hero who built it, and we can ask them directly.